# Custom plugin files updated code is not showing in admin panel though cache is cleared

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cache, custom, plugin

I have created a custom module. Controller files are working fine. I am trying to update my module MySQL version and adding new fields to the module in block folder files but they are not applying in the Magento panel. I've cleared cache and refreshed the index. Still not working.
magento version-1.9
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you update your codes to your question?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Where is the code?